# How to determine if a matrix is a 3D cartesian rotation matrix

Tags: matrices, 3d, rotations

If you have a 3x3 matrix and you want to determine whether it can be a 3D cartesian rotation matrix or not, what's the best and quickest way to determine this? What's the best starting point?

I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: I believe every rotation matrix is orthogonal. Try multiplying your matrix by its transpose. If you don't get the identity then it cannot be a rotation matrix. See here where it says "every rotation is described by a $3\times 3$ orthogonal matrix...": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group

Answer (score 0):

The sufficient checks are:

1. Check that matrix is orthogonal $MM^T=I$
2. Check that matix isn't a reflection: $\det M>0$